# How do I make a link open an Instagram page in an app installed on flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to know how to make a link open an Instagram page in an app if the app is installed on a smartphone.

A simple way such as [www.instagram.com/example](http://www.instagram.com/example) links you to page by browser, which is not what I want.

How do I achieve this?
[image]

I want it to go to my Instagram page when I hit Mohammad Khashei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use url_launcher package and following approach

```
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(
  'https://www.instagram.com/<INSTAGRAM_PROFILE>/',
  universalLinksOnly: true,
);
}
```

Comment: telegram @Darkko_33033